# Change tkinter entry widget multiple times after pressing a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a tkinter Entry widget and when a user presses a button the contents update:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

def abcdef(num):
    ent.config(state=NORMAL)
    ent.delete(0, 'end')
    ent.insert(0, num)
    ent.config(state = "readonly")
    print(num) #Just to check the code is being run

def changeEntry():
    for j in range(3):
            ent.after(1000, abcdef(j))



ent = Entry(widow, text="", state = "readonly", readonlybackground="white", font = "20")
ent.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "E")

btn = Button(window, text="Button", command=changeEntry)
btn.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "NESW", pady = 10, padx = 10)

window.mainloop()
```

When I press the button the window freezes for 3 seconds and then just displays the final number. How can I make it so when the user presses the button, the entry changes every second instead of just freezing for 3 seconds and only displaying the final one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *very* closely related: [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5767228) Same problem, except it's not a button command in your case. Here, it's the argument to `disp.after`.

Comment: what is `disp` ? Do you want the output in terminal?

Comment: @PratikKumar Sorry, that should've been ent

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with that `.after` call. The `.after` method tells Tkinter to call the function you pass it after the time interval has passed. But you're telling Tkinter to do 3 things after 1000 milliseconds have passed, so they'll all happen on top of each other. So you need to stagger the delays.

Secondly, you need to give `.after` a function to call when its time to call it. But your code calls the function and gives `.after` the return value of your function. We can fix that by wrapping the function call inside another function. A convenient way to do that is using `lambda`, giving the `lambda` a default argument it can pass to `abcdef`

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

def abcdef(num):
    ent.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    ent.delete(0, 'end')
    ent.insert(0, num)
    ent.config(state = "readonly")
    print(num) #Just to check the code is being run

def changeEntry():
    for j in range(3):
            ent.after(1000 * j, lambda num=j: abcdef(num))


ent = tk.Entry(window, text="", state = "readonly", readonlybackground="white", font = "20")
ent.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = "E")

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Button", command=changeEntry)
btn.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "NESW", pady = 10, padx = 10)

window.mainloop()
```

I've also replaced that "star" import with the neater `import tkinter as tk`. That makes it obvious which names come from Tkinter and which names are local to your program.

---

Bryan Oakley points out that we don't need that `lambda`, we can pass in arguments after the function name. See the [Basic Widget Methods](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) in the Tkinter docs for details. So we can re-write `changeEntry` like this:

```
def changeEntry():
    for j in range(3):
        ent.after(1000 * j, abcdef, j)
```

Thanks, Bryan!

Comment: You don't need `lambda` in the call to `after` in this specific case. You can pass in additional arguments: `ent.after(1000*j, abcdef, j)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Interesting! I vaguely remembered that, but I checked the docs and they didn't mention it, so I thought I must've been imagining things. ;) Correction: I checked the Event docs, not the `.after` docs. But I'll update my answer. Thanks!